# How to call the multiple action on single button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using mvc to disply the data from database here I want to display data based on customerid and agentid where user enter the customerid need to one action and agentid and for customerid for another action

```
public ActionResult Index(string ServiceProviderID)
    {
        var value = Convert.ToInt32(ServiceProviderID);
        var Query = (from u in db.collections
                 join pr in db.outstanding_master on u.CustomerID equals pr.LoanID
                     where pr.ServiceProviderID == value
                 select u);
        return View(Query);
    }

    public ActionResult AgentWise(string agentid)
    {

        var Query = (from u in db.collections

                     where u.AgentID == agentid
                     select u);
        return View(Query);

    }
```

view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "CollectionsReport"))
{      
@Html.CheckBox("ServiceProviderID",true)  
@Html.Label("ServiceProviderID", "ServiceProviderID")

@Html.CheckBox("AgentID",false)
@Html.Label("AgentID", "AgentID")
 <div class="editor-row">

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ServiceProviderID)
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="service" />
```

}

How to do this ? is it possible if not please give me suggestion for another approach? thankyou

Comment: How do you handle user inputs, if it is "customerid" or "agentid"?

Comment: yes my problem is that not have idea to handle user input, I aa tiring another approach based on checkbox selection

Comment: I think, the best way to add a flag, like your suggestion(checkbox, radio,...)

Comment: here how to know that checkbox checked and checked value?

Answer (score 1):

You have couple of options.

- If customerids and agentids are mutually exclusive, then first you can try find customer if found return customer view otherwise find agent and if found return agent view
- Have two separate input fields, one for customer id and another one for agent id and change the index action to accept two parameters and depending on which parameter is provided choose the correct view.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call two action using in one form this way, you can handle this in one action like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string ServiceProviderID)
    {
        var value = Convert.ToInt32(ServiceProviderID);

        var Query = (from u in db.collections
                 join pr in db.outstanding_master on u.CustomerID equals pr.LoanID
                     where pr.ServiceProviderID == value
                 select u);

        if(Query != null)
             return View(Query);

        else
        {
       var result = (from u in db.collections

                     where u.AgentID == ServiceProviderID
                     select u);
        return View(result); 
        }

    }
```

Comment: how it can check that given parameter is ServiceProviderID or customerid? here I am using one textbox and one button

Comment: You can put two parameters in form one with nane customerid and one with serviceid